# Jquery - Make a div move up/down while the user is scrolling the page, but ensure that div stays within another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I have a `#MyDiv` which currently automatically moves up/down within the screen when the user is scrolling their browser:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        $("#MyDiv").stop().animate({"marginTop": 
        ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px"}, 400);
    });
</script>
```

However, I have another `#DivContainer`, which houses `#MyDiv`. I would like to make sure that `#MyDiv` does not overextend outside the bounds of `#DivContainer` when scrolling.

Comment: Please provide complete code.

Comment: Why not scroll the #DivContainer then? That will ensure the child div stays within parent div

Comment: @cdoshi I'm trying to keep the #DivContainer stationary in my site layout. I want the child divs inside of it to be scrolled, but only to a certain degree.

Comment: I see. In that case you have to determine the position and height of parent as well as the child div and make sure child div's position never exceeds that of the parent